# I've been asked to resign and leave, what to do and how do I tell my team?

Tags: professionalism, united-states, resignation, team, termination

Due to various minor conflicts my manager has asked me to resign. Its a situation in which I'm really not a great fit for the team rather than any specific cause for termination. Because of that he gave me a few months to look for another job. Now I'm coming up with two weeks left on the job and I'm ready to let my team know that I'm leaving. But I haven't lined another job up yet. So I'm unsure how to announce my resignation without indicating that I've been terminated and in a way that will keep coworkers from asking about my next gig (since I don't have one). I want to keep the level of awkward at a bare minimum.
In the end, I have already handed in my resignation, so the topic of whether to resign or wait until they fire me is moot.

My question is therefore, what are some great ways to communicate to coworkers that I’m moving on without indicating it was an involuntary termination and that I’ve yet to secure another job?

My goal is to reduce awkwardness as much as possible.

---

EDIT: I sent the following email to my team yesterday afternoon

> Good afternoon Team,
>
> I wanted to let you know first that my last day at [business] will be on the [day]. I sincerely appreciate having had the opportunity to work with you all. I’ve learned so much from each of you. Even so I am looking forward to the new challenges my next position will bring. [My Boss] will be making the announcement to the full department tomorrow. I’ll be sure to send out my final farewell later later on with my contact information and linked-in profile.
>
> Best Wishes,
>
> [My Name]

When they ask, I'm considering saying something like "Ill let everyone know [where I'm going] in my final farewell letter". Hopefully I'll actually have an an offer by then.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78909/discussion-on-question-by-mplsamigo-ive-been-asked-to-resign-how-do-i-tell-my).

Comment: Is you resigning part of an agreement where they give you severance pay, or did the employer kindly ask you to leave?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Based on your comment, you are located in the United States.

If I were you, I would **not** resign. I would continue doing my job and give the best performance I could (**Edit:** Exactly for getting unemployment benefits - See first comment), then search and secure a job ASAP. Until **they** decide to fire me.

At this point, do NOT do what they are asking you to do. And once they fire you leave and take your experience and performance review/records with you, apply for unemployment benefits and get paid while finding the next job.

Now for the team, I would not pull my issues with my manager into the team. Don't tell the team anything and if you get fired, leave this worry behind and let the management figure out what to do and how to tell the team.

If for any reason you have to tell your team, I would just send an email. Something like this would work:

> Team,
>
> I have been asked to leave and effective last day is xx/xx/xxxx. It
>   was my pleasure meeting and working with each one of you. Please let
>   me know if you have any questions and I will be more than happy to help before I leave.

Comment: That’s easy to say. I also have to think about my family and consider the value of being given time to secure another job and not have a gap in my employment that I have to explain.

Comment: This is the way to go.  If you resign, you do not get unemployment benefits most of the time in the USA.

Comment: So I like this answer. The only thing I would change in order to meet my goal of *not* indicating I was asked to leave is maybe saying in my email that Ill be leaving and keeping my destination close to my vest for the time being.

Comment: @MplsAmigo Glad we were able to help. It is up to you really on what to type in the email, but if you were asked to leave, say that you were asked to leave. You never know what would happen in the future, for example maybe employees will request for you to come back? No one knows.

Comment: This is advice I wish I'd had when I was in this sort of situation. Don't quit unless you have an offer. Make them get rid of you. I will say that even if you resign you *may* be able to get unemployment benifits anyways if you mention that you were given an ultimatum (quit or be fired). This will depend on a lot of factors though.

Comment: @MplsAmigo Quite frankly. I think your team deserves to know the truth.  Why would you be deceptive about this?  Your team deserves to know how management is acting.  If they're firing people, that's useful information to them.  If you care about the people on your team you should be honest.  It may hurt, but it's a much better approach.

Comment: I think once you've handed in your resignation, it's too late to not resign

Comment: @MplsAmigo If you're just looking for a "what I'm doing next" just say you're freelancing. Which, let's face it, if you didn't have a job and someone gave you a freelance opportunity you'd probably take it!

Comment: If it's due to a poor fit, I would consider not saying anything except to the people I was closest to and could trust. For them, privately share contact information. I would augment @SandraK's letter to just mention which month you expect to leave, but not necessarily the exact date (unless it's in 2 weeks). For your next position, maybe something like "I am pursuing options for my next position, but it's still up in the air", but this is only if you feel the need to mention it. It's really no one's business but your own.

Comment: FYI, you *are* eligible for unemployment benefits in the US in cases of forced resignation. Unemployment hearing precedents make clear this includes both if your employer asks you directly to resign, or if they "force" resignation by making you miserable at work or your job impossible to perform.

Comment: Re: @reve_etrange 's comment, not only is that true, it's a good idea to accept resignation when asked to resign. You are only eligible for unemployment if you were not fired or asked to resign for performance reasons. Accepting resignation is often the best compromise when performance/fit is in question, but not bad enough to warrant outright firing. Your employer is likely to not challenge your unemployment benefits claim if you make the separation easy. If you resist, they might fight your claim for unemployment benefits and give bad references to future employers.

Comment: Staying at job and forcing the employer to initiate the firing seems like a bad idea. The OP was given MONTHS of advance notice, that's extraordinarily generous. Even so, not having a job lined up isn't particularly embarrassing, harmful to subsequent hiring chances, yes, but not something ex-coworkers would look down on you for. Much better to resign using the well-written letter and then privately communicate the actual circumstances to 1 or 2 trusted co-workers in a face-to-face conversation.

Answer (score 40):

Since you don't have a new job lined up, I would be honest with your team, and say that you didn't feel you were a good fit, so you and the manager agreed to part ways.  I would emphasize that this was a mutual decision, and you've thought about it for a while.  The point to all this is to also tell them you do not have a new job lined up.  This would trigger them to make suggestions or connect you with other companies.  This is actually a great time to network, using your existing team.  Hope this help, and good luck!  Jim

Comment: That's a good point I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 25):

So far it sounds like you have been passively accepting of anything that happens to you. A lot of the solution could lie in **going proactive**

Talk to your manager, in private. Tell him that although you are okay with leaving the company they should be the one to initiate proceedings. If they want you to leave, they should set the date. If they don't? Tell your manager that you will assume nothing has changed and that you plan to be professional about it until you find another job.

Why? Because *this turns it from your problem to theirs.* They thought they could get rid of you with the minimum of fuss, prove them wrong (note that just doing your job until you get fired counts as 'fuss' in this case, I do not recommend going postal.)

Now if worst comes to worst and you do get fired before one of your options turns up, you can benefit from any unemployment benefits. Explaining a "gap in your employment" is not nearly as big a thing in the modern economy as it once was.

Comment: Well, now I guess hind sight is 20/20. It’s the first time I’ve experienced something like this. Unfortunately I’ve already submitted my resignation not understanding all my options. Hopefully this will help somebody else in a similar situation.

Comment: I like this answer best if my question had been, "How do I handle being asked to resign". If you can edit your answer and include a few options that answers my actual question Ill mark it as the answer.

Comment: This is my current situation - I was let go for performance issues, but I felt that management wanted me to resign.  If I had resigned, I would not have gotten unemployment benefits and would be marched out the door the second I submitted the resignation.  

So long as your situation was not gross misconduct and didn't cause abject harm to the company or to yourself (e.g. coming into work drunk/high, fighting, stealing, falsifying documents), you should be OK with unemployment benefits.

Answer (score 11):

In many industries in the US, it is socially acceptable to state that you would rather not disclose your next employer. That information is yours to share or not share in any country and industry, but YMMV as social convention may differ depending on those 2 factors.
**EDIT:** As you clarified that the industry is software in the US, I can say definitively that "I don't want to disclose that." is an acceptable and professional response to "Where are you working next?". In fact, I had done that at my previous place of employment, despite having already accepted a job offer. I did not want either a) persons following me to my new job or b) persons I didn't see eye-to-eye with perhaps acting unprofessionally (not that I would be worth the effort to them, I'm just paranoid about that).

That being said, if you don't have a job lined up, why are you resigning? Resignation is voluntary, if you don't have another job lined up, make them fire you rather than resigning, as in many jurisdictions, unemployment can be tied to the form of separation. Additionally, a verbal "You need to quit" that isn't backed up with any sort of HR driven process holds no water. To fire you, they will want a paper trail of the process to cover their tails in case you sue for wrongful dismissal (again, assuming USA).

If it's just disagreements with your boss, and no true violations of company policy or local legal codes, the proper move on the part of the company may be to move you to a different business unit/department/management chain.

Comment: don't mention it @MplsAmigo , I've been stuck in similar situations and have not always made the best decisions, so I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 5):

I was in your position in October of last year, however I fired myself out of my own initiative.

I did not hide anything from the people I worked with; I just told them the plain truth, that I was tired some things were not working smoothly for a couple of years, that I had a couple of lined up opportunities but that would firstly take some longish deserved holidays with my wife.

I clearly do not see the source of your apprehension in having a work gap. Nowadays it is pretty common. Many people choose to took a sabbatical break and go in holidays, to prepare for a certification, or simply to work independently.

PS. I also mentioned in subsequent interviews I went out because I was not happy for a good while and nothing was done about it and as of the gap, was recharging my batteries in a couple of months gap, and taking a more wide view of the world travelling. All interviewers took my explanations fairly well, including my current job, except for one place where I was criticized for having an independent mind/opinion different of my upper management and travelling while unemployed. I would not like to work with such small minded people anyway, they seemed more interested in a desperate, low-paid serf than a smart, productive employee.

PS2. While we took a couple of months off, I have a workmate in my current job who told me he took one year off with his wife for travelling.

Comment: Did you also pay yourself unemployment?  :) How you leave the job is critical to whether you get unemployment: was it your idea or theirs, and if theirs, was there a really good reason.  The government doesn't care about soft verbiage like "was asked to resign" or "fired myself".  They are laid off and quit, respectively.

Comment: @Harper There are no semantics here. After 3 years of  being tired of mismanagement  and not seeing my new position of 5 years not being reflected in my performance evaluation, and middle manage taking the credits for my accomplishments,  I decided enough was enough, and resigned a week after my last evaluation objectives for the next two years being drafted. I always get amazed how it is so hard some people getting their concept on their own reality. As I said, I decided to resign *myself* and take some time off. Is it so difficult to grasp life is not all about money?

Comment: ....and that besides the employee, there is a person that is might not be not a mindless drone employee living paycheck-to-paycheck? Does that offend you existing people like that? Cannot get your comment. People also fire (bad) bosses, metaphorically speaking. At least people with a spine. That is why I did not like that interview...had a couple of guys like you whose concept of reality could not admit having an employee with his own opinion and free will and not a robot.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but an important one, and I wanted to focus on the actual message.

Given that, as the question stated, it's a done deal, my route would be to send an email to the team something like this:

> Looking back over the last xx months, I came to realize that I was not a good fit for this (team/environment/company; no need to say why).  I've discussed it with (my manager), and decided that it was time to move on.
>
> I'm actively looking for a position as X (describe what you are looking FOR, not something you are trying to avoid), and would appreciate any contacts you can suggest.
>
> I've (enjoyed/learned a lot/whatever positive aspect you can name) working with you all.  Please feel free to (contact me/LinkedIn/Facebook/etc.)
>
> Cheers,

This keeps all relationships cordial, doesn't place blame on your manager or company (whether any is deserved or not is immaterial), indicates your desire to network, and doesn't involve any nasty little details.  The fact that you didn't provide more info should be taken as a sign that you don't want to offer any more.  If there is a co-worker that you are close to, you can go in to more privately, but remember never to burn any bridges.

Also remember that there are recommendations to be had, both from the manager and coworkers.  It's possible that you could still get a recommendation from your manager even though you were pushed out, especially if they feel bad (but the time to ask is when you are terminated, not later, and try to get a written letter).  If it was simply a bad fit, they can always praise those skills that you did have, and not go into the areas of shortcomings; also, THEY don't want to burn any bridges, since any of you might cross paths in the future.

Comment: Re "old thread": This question's only a few hours old, and questions on Stack Exchange are treated timelessly anyway (there's even [a necromancer badge](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer)).

Comment: 10 hours is not that old...

Comment: This is a fantastic answer!  This should be the "accepted" answer, in my opinion!